# Get an object's name as the value of this

Tags: javascript-objects, console.log

I am trying to understand the value of *this* at different points in a script. Questions similar to mine have been answered in this forum but those answers are considerably above my current learning level.

In my code experiments, I am using console.logs to return the *this* value. The value returned is always as expected, but the format of the returned value is inconsistent, which leads me to wonder why.

This code returns the expected Window object for the first 3 log commands to be executed but returns only the object literal for the 4th command, executed from the object's method.

```
var myName = {
    name: "James",
    sayName: function() {
        console.log(this, 4);
        console.log(this.name)
    }
}

console.log(this, 1);  
function myFunction() {
    console.log(this, 2);
    function nestFunction() {
        console.log(this, 3);
        myName.sayName();
    } 
    nestFunction();
}

myFunction();
```

I have 3 questions: Why doesn't console.log return the name of the object?  Is there a way to make it do so?  Is there a simple way to do that other than console.log?  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Ok I was going through your code to see what you specifically mean

here is the short explanation as to why THIS is different in some of the places

***This***  keyword refers to the object it belongs to. Generally you used it to refer to the global window object .That's what is reflecting in your console log 1,2,3 .

Calling ***this*** in static javaScript object will return the javaScript object ,not the window object that is what is reflecting in the `console.log(this,4)`.

So it gives you a way to call elements inside a static object .
 Another way to understand **`this`** keyword is to look at constructors .The best example of the keyword

`this`

is inside a constructor function

```
    var myObj = function(){

            function myObj(ref)
            {
                    this.name = "";
                    this.Item = "";
                    this.ref = ref;
                    this.speak();
             }

             myObj.prototype.speak =function()
             {
                     this.name = 'James';
                     this.item = 'cheese';

                     console.log(this.ref)
                     //and the constuctor object
                     console.log(this)
             }

             return myObj;
    }();

    var e = new myObj('a Refrence string');
```

This should give you a basic understanding of how ***this*** works

here is more info to get you started  [Wschools.com](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_this.asp)

Comment: Try "myName.Name" to get the name returned .
 If you want the keys of the Static object then use  Object.keys(myName) to push it to an array . 

But if you want the name its "myName.name"

Comment: Jono, thank you for your answer.  I do know the meaning of _this_.  What I don't know is how to get the name of the object ("myName") as the return value of the console.log(this) in the object's method or by other means that don't require changing the object itself.  I'm guessing that may not be possible.  Thanks again for trying to help.

Comment: I have an answer to my question. In my code, _myObject_ is the variable to which I assigned the value of the object literal. I knew that _console.log(this, 4)_ would return the object that contains it but I made the mistake of thinking that _myObject_ would be the object returned, i.e. that the variable is the same as the value it contains.  So the answer to my question is: The object's method returns the object literal and not _myObject_ because a variable is something distinct from the value assigned to it. 
Jono, you were right! I had a faulty understanding of the meaning of "this" .

Comment: It took me a while as well to understand it its only when I started working with Constructor types that it became clear . The next challenge I had with with the keyword was binding it to an event emmitter callback Handel and listener  . Even though the event was declared as a prototype It didn't  know what this was ... I eventually solved it by using the keyword "bind" used at the end of the function statement i.e  
MyObject.prototype.click =  function(e)
{
 //the code 
this.emit();
} .bind(this);